# how to draw mathematical triangle using degrees in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, polygon

how to draw mathematical triangle like Scalene Triangles, isosceles triangle using some degrees in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the math (which I'm assuming you can figure out or google for) there's a couple APIs you could use.

- [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) can let you easily draw lines on a bitmap.
- You can also use the built-in Silverlight geometry pathing either in
  XAML or C# code behind:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189068%28VS.95%29.aspx

One thing to be aware of is the coordinate system in Silverlight has the Y axis flipped from most mathematical descriptions of geometry.

Comment: I tried normal triangle using polygon shape. but i don't know how to draw mathematical triangle using some degree values

Comment: Perhaps the use of Polar Coordinates will help: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarCoordinates.aspx .NET's `System.Math` class has a variety of trigonometry methods (sin, cos, tan) which you can use.  Just be aware, the methods take radians instead of degrees, so you'll need to convert to radians first.